# How to update multiple rows with repeats based on values in one column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset of website image metrics that need `NA` data overwritten. Previously, I joined two tables on a `website_index`. However, now I need to go back and add multiple columns of data for multiple rows. I am not sure if I can once again join the table (will it create duplicates since some of the data is already there?) Should I use another method?

I should add that this spans 1000s of lines of data. The `website_index` is repeated multiple times, and there are 20+ columns of values I'm trying to add. So I'd prefer not to use `c()` to manually add column values to the row, as I might make an copying error of all of the values.

An example of the dataset I'm trying to update

```
website_index metric1 metric2
1               NA      NA
2               NA      NA
3              "red"    "green"
4              "blue"   "green"
```

Would like the dataset to look like this

```
website_index metric1 metric2
1              "value1"   "value2"
2              "value3"   "value4"
3              "red"    "green"
4              "blue"   "green"
```

Comment: You'll probably want to complete the example with some info about the rule that leads to the desired output. Maybe you have another table to show that matches this example (since you mention a join)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to replace the `NA` to `"value"`.

```
dat[is.na(dat)] <- "value"
dat
#   website_index metric1 metric2
# 1             1   value   value
# 2             2   value   value
# 3             3     red   green
# 4             4    blue   green`
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "website_index metric1 metric2
1               NA      NA
                  2               NA      NA
                  3              'red'    'green'
                  4              'blue'   'green'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For insanely large data sets where memory and speed is required, following solution using `data.table` should be faster. For normal scenarios use solution by @www

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
for (j in names(dat)) set(dat, which(is.na(dat[[j]])), j, "value")
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize my question was worded vaguely with them all saying "value" - I need multiple different values to be added across the columns, so this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATING TO MATCH OP'S EDITS**

A solution using base for loops.

```
#example data frame
x <-  data.frame(web = c(1,2,3,4), metrc = c(NA,NA,'red','blue'), metrc2 = c(NA, NA, 'green','green'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#initializing empty vector
l <- c()

#creating "value" with a count of NAs in data frame
for(i in 1:sum(is.na(x))){
    l[[i]] <- paste0('value',i)
 }

#nested for loop that check each row, column, fills in first item from the vector
#to the NA, and removes item from vectors.

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
    if(is.na(x[i,j])) {

      x[i,j] <- l[[1]]
      l <- l[l!=l[1]]

    }
  }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way? Doubtful. However, I am not really sure this answers your true question as you mentioned joining tables. Perhaps adding an example table that you would want to join as @Frank suggested would help?